Category and archive issue
Help, please.
I have 4 category pages.  When I publish a post on a specific category page it shows on all category pages after creating an archive page.
But I want specific archive page for specific category page.

You shouldn't need to create category pages, they're automatically generated by WordPress. Could you explain what you're doing in a little more detail?
